# RegEx: Matching commas enclosed by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
""a"","""b""",""12,3"","d"
```

I need to match all commas enclosed by quotes, regardless of the number of quotes, so the result would be:

```
a
b
12,3
d
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for single commas found within any pair of quotes, or can there be multiple, e.g. "a,b,c", "d"?

Comment: If you're just trying to split the string, it might suffice to match \"+\,\"+

Comment: I think my question is wrong, but your answer is what i was trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: How about extracting second [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of [`("+)([^"]*)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/Zz1Rxk/1). See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k31rdLm3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the string first, then replace the quotes in the parts

```js
let s = '""a"","""b""",""12,3"","d"';

let r = s.split(/(?!,\w+),/);
r = r.map(e => e.replace(/"/g, ""));
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var test = '""a"","""b""",""12,3"","d"'

test = test.match(/(\b[0-9a-z,]+)/gmi)

console.log('match: ', test)
```

match:  [ 'a', 'b', '12', '3', 'd' ]